# Differential Geometry Generalized Functions

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, vector-spaces

A vector in differential geometry becomes a functional on the manifold $M$, namely

$X_{p,\gamma}:C^{\infty}(M)\to \mathbb{R}$,

$X_{p,\gamma}f=\left.\dfrac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}(f\circ \gamma)$.

This reminds me a lot of what a *generalized function* is. Namely a generalized function "eats" up a smooth test function (that vanishes outside a bounded subset of $M$ etc etc) and "spits" out a number, however, symbolically like

$\left< f, \cdot \right>: C^{\infty}(U)\to \mathbb{R}$,

$\left< f,\phi \right>=\int f(x)\phi(x)dx$.

It feels that there must be some sort of connection here between these two concepts, but I am totally missing the details. (or the point!)

Comment: Can you clarify your question? If I understood what you want, you can look the vector fields like a section of a vector bundle. Maybe it gonna help you.

Comment: My questiion is: Can you really look at vector fields (besides as sections of vector bundles) as some sort of generalized functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems to be a bit difficult to answer to me. Formally, the answer certainly is yes, directional derivatives in a point do define distributions. Still, in my opinion this is a rather unnatural way to view this operation. Just think about the case of $\mathbb R^n$. You can certainly interpret a point $x\in\mathbb R^n$ and a vector $v\in\mathbb R^n$ as a generalized function, since $f\mapsto Df(x)(v)$ is a linear map. This is the directional derivative of the delta-distribution at $x$ in direction $v$, which of course is an very important concept. I dont think that you would view it as a way to understand directional derivatives of smooth functions.

Here the situation is similar. The curve $\gamma$ is used to define a direction at a point, namely the direction $\gamma'(0)$ in the point $\gamma(0)$. Then you can differentiate smooth functions in that direction and you gave the the defining formula for this, which simply reflects the fact that the chain rule should be applicable to $f\circ\gamma$. You can interpret this as defining a generalized function (the directional derivative of $\delta_{\gamma(0)}$ in direction $\gamma'(0)$) but this seems to be a rather roundabout way to view things.

Comment: My question came up in the following analogy I had in mind: A typical vector field on a finite dimensional manifold $M$ looks like $X=\xi^i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ (summation convention employed). Could it be that if $M$ is somehow (?) infinite dimensional (Banach Space?) vector fields would look like $X=\int dx \  \xi(x) \dfrac{\delta}{\delta \phi(x)}$? Does this make sense? Namely to imagine variations as some sort of "covector" basis $\delta A(x)$ and variational derivatives as basis for vector fields?

Comment: I am not sure what you are after, but to write any vector field as a linear combination of the $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ you only need that any vector in $\mathbb R^n$ can be written as a linear combination of standard basis vectors (and correspondingly any directional derivative can be written as a linear combination of partial derivatives). So I don't really see a connection to the point of view you are proposing.